# How can I delete data from a hub with different satellites?

Tags: sql

Imagine I have a hub (`employeeID`) and three different satellites: `NameSAT`, `AddressSAT` and `SalarySAT`.

Is there a procedure that allows me to delete `employee` with `ID = something` from a hub and also the respective satellites?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Data Vault is an architecture and usually several different databases are used to reflect that behaviour, you'd need to implement the deletion routines yourself.

Comment: That is exactly my quesion. Can you give me an example of a delete routine?

Comment: Since I do not know your data vault model, the schema and the database system I cannot give an example. Still, there are DELETE examples and STORED PROCEDURE examples for your RDBMS in the interwebs.